# How to return JSON from django simple_tag?

Tags: python, json, django, amcharts

I am new to Django, here I have integrated amchart with my application. I have created a simple_tag method to set a value to dataProvider.

Here my amchart code is,

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv-{{ server.id }}", {
                  "theme": "chalk",
                  "type": "serial",
                  "dataProvider": '{% get_space_occupation server.SpaceOccupied %}',
                  "valueAxes": [{
                      "stackType": "3d",
                      "unit": "GB",
                      "position": "left",
                      "title": "Memory space rate",
                  }]
```

When I try to return an array of hashes it is not returning the JSON as expected. Here my code in the custom template tag is,

```
from django import template
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.core import serializers

@register.simple_tag
def get_space_occupation(space_occupied):
    data = [{
        "Drive": "C",
        "FreeSpace": 131,
        "Total": 250
    }]
    # datas_serialized = serializers.serialize('json', data)
    return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

This is what I'm getting in my template,

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv-1", {
                  "theme": "chalk",
                  "type": "serial",
                  "dataProvider": '&lt;JsonResponse status_code=200, &quot;application/json&quot;&gt;',
                  "valueAxes": [{
                      "stackType": "3d",
                      "unit": "GB",
                      "position": "left",
                      "title": "Memory space rate",
                  }]
```

Please help me to resolve this issue and correct me if I were wrong.

Comment: You don't have to return `JsonResponse`. It's not a json data, it's response including json data.

Comment: @seuling if I returned
 without JsonResponse this is what I'm getting in the template [{&#39;Drive&#39;: &#39;C&#39;, &#39;Total&#39;: &#39;249GB&#39;, &#39;FreeSpace&#39;: &#39;203GB&#39;}]. The double quotation replaced by &#39. Please guide me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: try using `json()`. `return json.dumps(data)`

Comment: Hi @seuling now the double quotes changed into &quot; -> "dataProvider": "[{&quot;Drive&quot;: &quot;C&quot;, &quot;FreeSpace&quot;: 131, &quot;Total&quot;: 250}]"

Comment: you can use `safe` filter in tempalte. but in this situation, I'm not sure it works.. So use `autoescape off`. I will write answer with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send json data from your request. And receive in script.

```
@register.simple_tag
def get_space_occupation(space_occupied):
    data = [{
        "Drive": "C",
        "FreeSpace": 131,
        "Total": 250
    }]
    return json.dumps(data)
```

In script, you have few option.

First, try `autoescape`

```
{% autoescape off %}
var dateProvider = '{% get_space_occupation server.SpaceOccupied %}'
{% autoescape %}
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv-{{ server.id }}", {
              "theme": "chalk",
              "type": "serial",
              "dataProvider": dataProvider,
              "valueAxes": [{
                  "stackType": "3d",
                  "unit": "GB",
                  "position": "left",
                  "title": "Memory space rate",
              }]
```

If it doesn't work, use `JSON.parse` for your data.

like this

```
var dateProvider = JSON.parse('{% get_space_occupation server.SpaceOccupied %}');
```

Comment: I tried with the 'autoescape' and I got 'autoescape' tag requires exactly one argument and on the other hand, I tried with 'JSON.parse' even it also didn't help me.